# How to Stream an image to a client app in asp.net web api?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, streaming, asp.net-web-api

I have to retrieve an image from the disk or a web link , resize it and stream it to the client app. This is my controller method.

```
[HttpPost]
    [ActionName("GetImage")]
    public HttpResponseMessage RetrieveImage(ImageDetails details)
    {
        if (!details.Filename.StartsWith("http"))
        {
            if (!FileProvider.Exists(details.Filename))
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "File not found"));
            }

            var filePath = FileProvider.GetFilePath(details.Filename);

            details.Filename = filePath;
        }                

        var image = ImageResizer.RetrieveResizedImage(details);

        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();

        // Save image to stream.
        image.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);        

        var response = new HttpResponseMessage();
        response.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
        response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition
            = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
        response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = details.Filename;
        response.Content.Headers.ContentType
            = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");

        return response;
    }
```

And this is how am sending the web link(in this case) and receiving the image at the client app end.

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:27066");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/octet-stream"));

            ImageDetails img = new ImageDetails { Filename = "http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-W6kMpFQ5pKU/TiUwJJc8iSI/AAAAAAAAAJ8/c3sJ7hL8SOw/s1600/2011-audi-q7-review-3.jpg", Height = 300, Width = 200 };

            var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/Media/GetImage", img);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); // Throw on error code.

            var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

            FileStream fileStream = System.IO.File.Create("ImageName");
            // Initialize the bytes array with the stream length and then fill it with data
            byte[] bytesInStream = new byte[stream.Length];
            stream.Read(bytesInStream, 0, (int)bytesInStream.Length);    
            // Use write method to write to the specified file
            fileStream.Write(bytesInStream, 0, (int) bytesInStream.Length);



            MessageBox.Show("Uploaded");
```

The image is being retrieved from the web link and the resizing is done properly but am not sure if its being streamed proeprly as its creating a 0kb file with "ImageName" when received at client app. Can anyone please tell me where am going wrong? I have been banging my head about it all day :(

Comment: What's the value of `stream.Length` on the client?

Comment: zero :( thats why i think the streaming is not being done properly. But when i put a breakpoint at "image.Save" in the controller method the stream shows a considerable length which means the image is being saved to the stream. The problem could be that the stream is not being attached to the HttpContent properly or something else. Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you see in Fiddler? Did the server send something into the response stream?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try resetting the position of the memory stream before passing it to the response:

```
stream.Position = 0;
response.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
```

I suppose that your image resizing library is leaving the position of the memory stream at the end.